# Web Scraping Problem - Returns empty table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to grab the search result as a table from this website:
https://www.handelsregister.de/rp_web/result.do?Page=1

but it returns an empty table. I am using this code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from requests import get

url = "https://www.handelsregister.de/rp_web/result.do?Page=1"  
html = urlopen(url)

soup = BS(html, 'lxml')  
table = soup2.find_all('table')
#table = soup.find_all('table', class_ = 'RegPortErg')
#table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'RegPortErg'})
print(table)
```

Comment: When I go to that link, there are no search results.

Comment: if you go to this link: https://www.handelsregister.de/rp_web/welcome.do                         and select advance search then choose 'Baden-Württemberg' you will get result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a very clean table to parse, but you can use the `requests.post()`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.handelsregister.de/rp_web/mask.do?Typ=e"  


payloads = {
'suchTyp': 'e',
'registerArt': 'HRA',
'registerNummer': '',
'bundeslandBW': 'on',
'registergericht': '',
'schlagwoerter': '',
'schlagwortOptionen': '2',
'niederlassung': '',
'rechtsform': '',
'postleitzahl': '',
'ort': '',
'strasse': '',
'ergebnisseProSeite': '10',
'btnSuche': 'Find'}

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'}

html = requests.post(url, data=payloads, headers=headers)

tables = pd.read_html(html.text)

table = tables[1]
```

**Output:**

```
print (table)
                                                    0             ...                                       4
0                                        Firma / Name             ...                                     NaN
1   Baden-Württemberg  Amtsgericht  Freiburg  HRA ...             ...                                     NaN
2                                                 NaN             ...              AD  CD  HD  DK  UT  VÖ  SI
3    Baden-Württemberg  Amtsgericht  Ulm  HRA  726084             ...                                     NaN
4                                                 NaN             ...              AD  CD  HD  DK  UT  VÖ  SI
5   Baden-Württemberg  Amtsgericht  Mannheim  HRA ...             ...                                     NaN
6                                                 NaN             ...              AD  CD  HD  DK  UT  VÖ  SI
7   Baden-Württemberg  Amtsgericht  Mannheim  HRA ...             ...                                     NaN
8                                                 NaN             ...              AD  CD  HD  DK  UT  VÖ  SI
9                                                 NaN             ...                                     NaN
10                                                NaN             ...                                     NaN
11                                                NaN             ...                                     NaN
12  Baden-Württemberg  Amtsgericht  Mannheim  HRA ...             ...                                     NaN
13                                                NaN             ...              AD  CD  HD  DK  UT  VÖ  SI
14  Baden-Württemberg  Amtsgericht  Freiburg  HRA ...             ...                                     NaN
15                                                NaN             ...              AD  CD  HD  DK  UT  VÖ  SI
16                                                NaN             ...                                     NaN
17                                                NaN             ...                                     NaN
18                                                NaN             ...                                     NaN
19  Baden-Württemberg  Amtsgericht  Mannheim  HRA ...             ...                                     NaN
20                                                NaN             ...              AD  CD  HD  DK  UT  VÖ  SI
21                                                NaN             ...                                     NaN
22                                                NaN             ...                                     NaN
23  Baden-Württemberg  Amtsgericht  Stuttgart  HRA...             ...                                     NaN
24                                                NaN             ...              AD  CD  HD  DK  UT  VÖ  SI
25                                                NaN             ...                                     NaN
26                                                NaN             ...                                     NaN
27  Baden-Württemberg  Amtsgericht  Freiburg  HRA ...             ...                                     NaN
28                                                NaN             ...              AD  CD  HD  DK  UT  VÖ  SI
29                                                NaN             ...                                     NaN
30                                                NaN             ...                                     NaN
31  Baden-Württemberg  Amtsgericht  Mannheim  HRA ...             ...                                     NaN
32                                                NaN             ...              AD  CD  HD  DK  UT  VÖ  SI

[33 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help. One question is it possible to grab the next page

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of `html = urlopen(url)`:

```
html = urlopen(url).read()
```